# Allow background-image to behave like <img>

Tags: image, html, background-image

I'm creating a homepage using Twitter Bootstrap, and I want to create a "hero image" (that does NOT use bootstrap's hero unit.) I want a large picture at the top of the page, that you can put text on. You can't use img tags because any headings you type appear below the image. I then tried using divs with background-image:, but then the image won't adjust to fit the browser, nor will the entire image appear, it just shows part of it behind the text. I tried manually setting the div size, but I want the image to automatically adjust to the browser.

Comment: Can you show us the code you ended up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplistic solution that uses absolute positioning for the heading.

I have centered the text of the heading and your needs might require something other than what I have provided.

The container `<div id="hero">` takes on the size and shape of the elements it contains, the image and the header.  Since the header is absolutely positioned it is taken out of the document flow and the div is now the same size as the image that is contained within it.  Adding `position: relative;` to the containing `<div id="hero">` allows you to position the `<h2>` relative to the container `<div id="hero">` rather than some other ancestor element like another containing `<div>`, `<body>` or `<html>`.

## CSS

```
#hero {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;  /* not required for re-sizing */
    position: relative;
}
#hero img {
    max-width: 100%;  /* for re-sizing in browser */
}
#hero h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

## HTML

```
 <div id="hero">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-800-400-9.jpg" />
    <h2>Some Heading</h2>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always try using css z-index property

```
#bg_img {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

So whatever text/headings you have, they will always appear on the heading not behind it